# python flask redirect(url_for()) not working

Tags: python, flask

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/login')
def showLogin():
    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def checkLogin():
    if request.method=="POST":
        try:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        
        except Exception:
            print(Exception)

    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

**login.html**

```
<form class='login-form'>
    <input type='text' name='inputText' id='inputText'>
    <button type='submit' name='btnLogin' id='btnLogin'>
</form>
```

**home.html**

```
<p>Hello!</p>
```

When I press the button (considering that I am on the login page) I want to redirect to the 'home' page regardless if the text field is empty or not. The problem is, it does not redirect to home when clicking the button.

Comment: Why do you have two login routes? That's most likely the issue.

Comment: And it would be a good idea be more explicit about where the form data should be submitted - add a target attribute.

Answer (score 1):

your form should have **method** attribute with value 'post'.

**login.html**

```html
<form method="post" class='login-form'>
    <input type='text' name='inputText' id='inputText'>
    <button type='submit' name='btnLogin' id='btnLogin'>
</form>
```